# npm install failing in alpine based docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run a node server in an Alpine based Docker image. However, it's failing on npm install. I would appreciate some help in figuring out what the issue is. Here is the Dockerfile
[image]

Here is the error when 'npm install' tries to run
[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting `.node-gyp` from `$HOME` folder?

Comment: You seem to have attached a screen shot in place of your Dockerfile; `docker build` doesn't understand PNG files.  Can you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your project depedencies requires an X window development package `libXext` which is not being install in your `apk add...` command.

Add the `libxext-dev` Alpine package, for instance.